# HTML Text in Button not working / overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have `buttons` inside a `nav` and the content of the buttons are overlapping, I wans't able to figure out what was causing it.

How can I prevent overlapping of the button contents?

```css
body,html
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav
{
    background-color: #e05138;
    height: 82px;
    width: 100%
}
button
{

  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: white;

  text-decoration: none;

  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;

  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px;

  float: right;

  width: 100px;

  line-height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My web Page</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
 
      <button type="button" name="Contact">Contact</button>
      <button type="button" name="About Me">About Me</button>
 
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you have a `fixed width` ! When there's too much content the button can not expand itself automatically.

Comment: See the problem at its very root here is incorrect spacing between the area the text is allowed to take up set by the code 5px, and the height the text actually takes up browser default which is why the text sits on top of itself. I liken changing the height of the button in this specific example to cutting a hole in the top of your car because you were too tall. You would get a car that fit your height instead and then you wouldn't be getting wet in the rain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to define the height of your buttons with "height" instead of "margin"

you can see the fixed code here:
https://codepen.io/parisotdev/pen/qLoPbg

```
button { 
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 20px;
 height: 60px; /*this was margin: 30px*/
 margin: 5px;
 float: right;
```

Comment: ok so if he decides to have some long text : lets say `About Me asd asd asd as asd a` Then the same issue will occur. On the codepen : try using `About Me blablabla`

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you keep your line height >= your text size.

You have the line-height at 5px and the text size is going to be using the browser default which is ~14-16px.

Try setting your line height to 1.

```
button{
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Explain to me why.... if the line height is not the issue, simply changing the line height to 1 exactly how I said fixes the issue of the text laying on top of each other, which is verbatum the question.

https://jsfiddle.net/rifi2k/nh9w80j6/

The proof is in the fiddle...

Although there is little reason to set a fixed height or width on the button, there may be a requirement to have a fixed width or height on your button, and setting a line height of 5px when you don't have an equal text height is not going to do you any favors down the road when those two words do end up stacking on top of each other, which is the case with a fixed width on that button.

So pretty much in my opinion the lesson to be learned from this example is not don't fix the width or height, its don't set a 5px line height when your text height is 16px... Anyone else care to disagree...

OVERLAPPING, not WRAPPING. overlapping is a line-height issue, wrapping is a fixed width issue

Comment: line height isn't the issue here. A `fixed width` is. The button has ~30px of padding and the text length is too much to be kept in the same line and therefore it is moved to the new line. OP should stop using fixed with on his buttons since it could cause the same issue in the future, when the text is long enough to not be able to stay in a single row.

Comment: Also to add to why I'm for sure correct... OVERLAPPING, not WRAPPING. overlapping is a line-height issue, wrapping is a fixed width issue

Comment: Ok let's assume you have a `line-height` of `1` and you keep a fixed `width` of `100px`. Now, if for some weird reason he decides to add another button which is to contain a longer text. Then the button will start expanding in height and it will get out of the navigation + it won't be able to keep its baseline (as it's siblings) ... if you now think "a width can be set and the button will stop expanding" yes , it would stop expanding but the content would overflow and that's just an extra problem to predict.

Comment: Yeah I get you but his question doesn't say any of that and the problem with his example is having a line height explicetly set to 5px, I don't seriously think anyone in the world that works on websites everyday would side with you over me.

Comment: When there's a `problem` several variables if not less must be taken into account and one efficient solution should be figured out. Your solution is not wrong, it's just inefficient and it's side effects will not be taken care of. In the future they may appear and be some extra PITA. (I will remove my downvote on your answer)

Comment: Agreed 100%, I just have to maintain that in the given example the most important thing to be taken away is to keep your line height always >= to the height of your text, it is just wrong in every circumstance to have that set up that way. But thanks for removing the down

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the button content is overlapping is because you are using a `fixed width` of `100px`. Since there's not enough of space for the contents, naturally it's forced to push the rest of the content to a new line.
What you can do here is to not use a fixed width and let the buttons decide for their own width.

```css
body,html
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav
{
    background-color: #e05138;
    height: 82px;
    width: 100%
}
button
{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
/*  width: 100px; */ /* COMMENTED THIS OUT */
  line-height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My web Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>

      <button type="button" name="Contact">Contact</button>
      <button type="button" name="About Me">About Me As much text as needed</button>

    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```